# Viewing route in GPX format together with POIs in KMZ format?

Tags: gpx, kmz

I've got a route for an ultra endurance cycling event (1000 miles unsupported) as well as a KMZ file with all of the churches in the country (Denmark).

Churches are of great help since they have running water and oftentimes toilets as well.

I'd like to study the course together with the churches plotted, but don't know how.

Comment: You can use Google Maps, see https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google earth is able to load lot of geographical data including GPX (and KMZ)

it's as simple as File>Open choose the GPX format and your GPX file

For more : https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148095?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

you can use eg. https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/.  On the right side you can import your gpx and kmz in different layers.  Then you can examine both.

Comment: Didn't accept the KMZ file.

https://www.korttilkirken.dk/filer/kirker.kmz